# Limit point of the specific set is in a set of the open cover.

Tags: general-topology, compactness

I am currently working on the exercise 2.26 of Baby Rudin.

[image]

It is mentioned the limit point $z$ must be in some set $G_n$. I don't get why should the limit point be covered as well, I tried proving that the set is closed but I am not able to get anywhere. Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1):

This is because the $G_n$ are a cover of the space $X$. Since $z$ is an element of $X$, it must be in one of the covering elements.

Comment: I am actually asking how is $z$ in $X$

Comment: @SrutiSarkar: $z$ is a limit point of $E$ in the space $X$ so of course $z\in X$: everything here is in $X$.

Comment: The assumption in the first line of the question states that every infinite subset (of $X$) has a limit point (in $X$).